# how to define a group in zabbix to show just some template items?

Tags: templates, debian, grouping, items, zabbix

In zabbix server I have a template with some items which are in `base-system` application and some others are in `call` applications. I have grouped my hosts named `base-system`, include that template, just to able to show the items in `base-system` application and the other one is so.

But now i don't know how to do that? (How to separate some items from a template in on group and some others to an other group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the list of items for a host, you will see a filter in the upper portion of the page. There, if you clear the "Host" field and set "Application" field to what you are looking for, you will get all items for that application on all hosts:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Your answer is just for separating items in configuration. HOW can i separate them in "Monitoring->overview" table? Is it possible in this case?

Comment: @shgnInc: Yes, you should upgrade to Zabbix 2.2. There, in "Monitoring" -> "Overview", it is possible to filter by application.